# Why does this query return a result in MySQL but not in php?

Tags: mysql, php

I have a query that isn't returning a result in php for a certain search term (that I believe it should), but when I test it directly in MySQL, it does return one. Other search terms return fine.

```
SELECT id,
  CONCAT_WS(' ',
            TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 SUBSTRING(`text`, 1, INSTR(`text`, 'rig') - 1 ),
                 ' ',
                 -8)
            ),
            TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING(`text`, INSTR(`text`, 'rig') ),
             ' ',
             7)
        )
  ) as `sample`, `title`, `url` 
FROM `documents` WHERE MATCH(text)
AGAINST('"rig"' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) OR MATCH(title)
AGAINST('"rig"' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

PHP:

```
if (!$result=$mysqliSiteSearch->query($query)) send("3149","e");
$hitArray=array();      
while ( $row=$result->fetch_assoc() ) { $hitArray[]=$row; }
```

I set up a .txt log file to record the result of:

```
print_r($result,true)
```

I tested a different search term which returns 8 results both directly in MySQL and when running the php script, and my log file shows:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 4
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 8
    [type] => 0
)
```

I then test the search term "rig", which, when testing the same query directly in MySQL, returns 1 row, but when running my php script, I get no hit, and my log file shows:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 4
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 0
    [type] => 0
)
```

Clearly I'm overlooking something, but what please?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Your are probably overlooking a typo somewhere between assigning your query to `$query`, and the line where you have `print_r($result,true)`.  Can you add that complete piece of code to your question?

Comment: check that the search string is actually ascii

Comment: Which engine?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%';`

Comment: Consider using `FULLTEXT(text, title)` and doing only one `MATCH`.